# Using Hugo, how can I access a variable from a partial file that is defined in base file?

Tags: global-variables, template-engine, partials, go-templates, hugo

I'm new to using [Hugo](http://gohugo.io) and Go Templates. How can I access a variable from a partial file that is defined in base file using Hugo?

For eg: I have an `index.html` file which contains code that reads the data stored in the `events.json` file in the data directory and stores it in a variable. How can I access that variable from another file?

**index.html**

```
{{ $events := .Site.Data.events }}

{{ partial "people" . }}
```

**people.html**

```
// access the events variable from the index.html
{{ $events }}
```

I really hope this makes sense. I can try and clarify more if needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0.15 introduced a [map that can be used for this](http://gohugo.io/templates/functions/#dict).

**index.html**

```
{{ $events := .Site.Data.events }}
{{ partial "people" (dict "events" $events) }}
```

**people.html**

```
// access the events variable from the index.html
{{ .events }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `dict` func:

`{{ partial "people" (dict "page" . "events" $events) }}`

You will then address them like `{{ .page.someVar }}` and `{{ .events.someVar }}` in the partial.

An alternative in your case could maybe, in the partial (as the previous poster said), address the `.Site.Data.events` directly from the partial.

Comment: good stuff, I was not aware of `dict`  . By the way, please fix the rounded bracket after `$events`, it should be curly brace. I can't suggest edit since it's less than 6 chars long.

Comment: Thanks for the correction (the rounded bracket is correct, btw).

Answer (score -2):

According to Hugo [documentation](http://gohugo.io/templates/partials/#variable-scoping):

> ... partial calls receive two parameters.
>
> 1. The first is the name of the partial and determines the file location to be read.
> 2. The second is the variables to be passed down to the partial.
>
> This means that the partial will only be able to access those variables. It is isolated and has no access to the outer scope.

This means, the `events` variable is *outside of the scope* of `people.html`. Your `people.html` cannot "see" it. One solution would be pass it down, like:

```
{{ partial "people" . $events }}
```

If it does not work, try different notation (`$` vs. `.`).

If that does not work, you can always call your data file again, without variable, just like in the [examples](http://gohugo.io/extras/datafiles/), that is, use `{{ .Site.Data.events }}` in your `people.html` partial.

Let me know in the comments how it goes, I'll try to improve my answer if necessary. I know it's a pain to get out of Hugo boundaries into Go territory :)

Comment: `{ partial "people" . $events }}` and using `$` or `.` notation also does not work

Comment: The first parameter in your sample is "people", the second one ".". $events is a third parameter that defines for what section the partial works. This does not solve the issue.